# Fixed NavBar Becomes Transparent Over Fixed Background Image

Tags: html, css

On my parallax style website, my navbar is transparent when it is laying over a background image which is also fixed but then becomes opaque when no longer over the top of one. I assume this is because they are competing with one another? I want the navbar to stay fixed as you scroll down and I want it to take precedent over the top of the background image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="navBar">
<li><a id=# section-white>Home</li>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="img1">
    <div class="titles">
        <span class="border">
            My Programming Journey
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="section section-navy">
    <h2>Section One</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod
    </p>
</section>

<div class="img2">
    <div class="titles">
        <span class="border">
            A Bit About Myself
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="section section-navy">
    <h2>Section Two</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
      eiusmod
    </p>
</section>

<div class="img3">
    <div class="titles">
        <span class="border">
            How I Got Into Programming
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="section section-navy">
    <h2>Section Three</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
</section>

<div class="img1">
    <div class="titles">
        <span class="border">
            My Programming Journey
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


.navBar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #696969;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.navBar li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px;
float: right;
text-align: 14px 16px;
}

.img1, .img2, .img3 {
position: relative;
opacity: 0.8;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Post your html code as well if you want us to help you

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` and `position: fixed` will not compete. They are assigned to different elements and these CSS rules work differently. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: I added the HTML. How would I go about providing an example?

Comment: Solved with z-index

Answer (score 1):

try the z-index in your CSS... z-index=1 will be above z-index=0 :)